# Get click event from gridview's child item in main activity from adapter

Tags: java, android, gridview, adapter

I have a GridView in my activity. I am having 2 elements in the GridView. One is an `ImageView` and the other is a `TextView`.

I want to perform an action when clicking the ImageView **only**, but I want this to happen in the activity and not in the GridView adapter.

I handle the `ImageView` click in the `getView()` of my adapter, but I do not want it that way. I want to handle it in the activity when calling:

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, items));

gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

        //THIS WORKS FINE
        String string = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text)).getText().toString();
        Log.d("string",string);

        //THE PROBLEM OCCURS HERE
        ImageView capture = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.capture);
        capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
    }
});
```

**//THE PROBLEM OCCURS HERE**

The action is supposed to happen the first time I click the `ImageView`, but it only happens on the second click and further.

This is where I am stuck with the issue. I want this action to occur on the first click and not on the second click.

Comment: Because you have two click listener each other inside. If you want seperate click for TextView and ImageView, you should use `getView()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the code block-

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

    String string = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text)).getText().toString();
    Log.d("string",string);

    //THE PROBLEM OCCURS HERE
    ImageView capture = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.capture);
    capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
}
```

Your imageview **capture** is adding any action after gridview is being clicked. So, after clicking first time it is executing and then setting click listener to imageview and then next click its executing its onClick block. So better, handle imageview click event inside adapter.

You can call method inside your activity from adapter class but you should implement `setOnClickListener` inside your adapter class.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in you activity.

Now, in adapter, onClick call that method using

```
((Activityname)context).methodname(parameters);
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me.

Answer (score 0):

with the help of interface, you can do that do one thing create an interface and implement it on your activity and get imageview click on the adapter and here initiate the interface and you will get the click inside the activity

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that on the first click you just *set* `OnClickListener` on your imageView, and so its `onClick()` method is not getting called. On the second click though, as the listener is already set, `onClick()` is invoked.

Instead of setting new Listener to your imageView each time an item in the grid clicked (which does not make any sense by the way), you should do either of these:

If imageView in each item has to be handled the same way, set `OnClickListener` to the imageView in the adapter, when creating a view.

If not, pass the interface for handling imageView clicks to the constructor of the adapter, and then, in the activity, implement this interface when creating an adapter.